# Can't do a partial upgrade

Tags: updates, partial-upgrade

My last update failed, so I need to do a partial upgrade, but every time I try, an alert comes up saying

```
cannot update precise to oneiric
```

The only option is close, and then the update is cancelled. Help?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Oneiric Ocelot means it's Ubuntu 11.10 which was released in October 13, 2011 and support ended in May 9, 2013.

Precise Pangolin means it's Ubuntu 12.04 LTS released in April 26, 2012.

[image]

> cannot update precise to oneiric

This is normal attitude since you can find the repository of non supported release. The old repositories is now under the "old-releases" `server old-releases.ubuntu.com` not the `archive.ubuntu.com`.

So mainly you have two choices to do:

1. Backup your data and then reinstall to a new supported version(12.04 - 14.04- 14.10 -15.04) and its better to use some [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) such 12.04 or 14.04
2. Do the trick:

edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`

You can do this with sed

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then update with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now try to upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Please take a look on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/ and for your case read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/Oneiric